Shannon's finite state transducer (FST) entropy theorem
I am trying to make sense of the proof of Shannon's theorem that a finite state transducer cannot increase the entropy of its input.
I would love some sort of drawing or intuitive formulation of it, but haven't found either. I'm not fluent with the notation — I’m working on that — so if you can think of a way to explain it in either English (even insane legalese-sounding English!) or with notation defined in jargon-light terms, I'd be very grateful.

Theorem 7: The output of a finite state transducer driven by a finite state statistical source is a finite state statistical source, with entropy (per unit time) less than or equal to that of the input. If the transducer is non-singular they are equal.
Let $\alpha$ represent the state of the source, which produces a sequence of symbols $x_i$; and let $\beta$ be the state of the transducer, which produces, in its output, blocks of symbols $y_j$. The combined system can be represented by the "product state space" of pairs $(\alpha, \beta)$. Two points in the space $(\alpha_1, \beta_1)$ and $(\alpha_2, \beta_2)$, are connected by a line if $\alpha_1$ can produce an $x$ which changes $\beta_1$ to $\beta_2$, and this line is given the probability of that $x$ in this case. The line is labeled with the block of $y_j$ symbols produced by the transducer. The entropy of the output can be calculated as the weighted sum over the states. If we sum first on $\beta$ each resulting term is less than or equal to the corresponding term for $\alpha$, hence the entropy is not increased. If the transducer is non-singular, let its output be connected to the inverse transducer. If $H'_1$, $H'_2$ and $H'_3$ are the output entropies of the source, the first and second transducers respectively, then $H'_1 \geq H'_2 \geq H'_3 = H'_1$ and therefore $H'_1 = H'_2$.

My best stab, so far, at what the proof is saying is this: the only factor that could in principle modulate the probability distribution (and so the entropy) of the output relative to that of the input would be the factor $\beta$, and the state of $\beta$ is controlled exclusively by an input distribution ($x$) given by the states of $\alpha$.
But I can't fully map that intuition to the mechanisms of the proof.
Finally, some notation confusions:

What does the $n$ in $\beta_n$ and $\alpha_n$ refer to? The execution step? Or is it indicative of the unique state of $\beta$ or $\alpha$, respectively? It can't be both.
He defines $\alpha$ as "the state of the source, which produces a sequence of symbols $x_i$." So are $\alpha$ and $x$ supposed to be part of their own FST? Or are they part of some arbitrary "stochastic producer of symbols"? If the latter, why do we require both $\alpha$ and $x$? If the former (i.e., if $\langle\alpha, x\rangle$ defines an FST, just like $\langle x, \beta, y\rangle$ defines an FST), this "input-symbol-producing" $\langle\alpha, x\rangle$ FST seems to be missing the distinction between input and output symbols.

